# What is this reference in wyrd sisters?

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld, witches

I am reading "Wyrd Sisters" by Terry Pratchett and came upon this paragraph:

> “Right!” He pointed a vibrating finger toward the stage and lowered his voice and, at that moment, a dramatic inspiration dived through the atmosphere and slammed into his creative node, causing him to say, **“Now I want you to get out there and give ’em hell. Not for me. Not for the goddam captain.”** He shifted the butt of an imaginary cigar from one side of his mouth to the other, and pushed back a nonexistent tin helmet, and rasped, **“But for Corporal Walkowski and his little dawg.”**

Obviously this is a reference to *something*, but I can't figure out what. I tried googling for it but found nothing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CCwxMvXPZo ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is clearly a reference to American war movies, probably WWII era, but I think it's an homage, not a reference to a specific movie. The dialog is surely not a direct quote, otherwise it would be found on Google.

*Walkowski* is undoubtedly an echo of *Kowalski*, a common Polish surname. Having a soldier called Kowalski is [kind of a trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/discussion.php?id=ybxue3ej8lwsjc0n26ev2hor). A [WWII era war movie](https://books.google.com/books?id=lQ3GZuKbidMC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=%22kowalski%22) would have at least a token non-Anglo-Saxon-European name, preferably Polish as Poland was an ally.

The character with the cigar and the helmet giving the pep talk is surely [“cigar chomping”](http://www.gettyimages.fr/detail/photo-d'actualit%C3%A9/george-c-scott-plays-cigar-chomping-us-army-general-photo-dactualit%C3%A9/88804021) [Patton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_S._Patton), who was the subject of a famous [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066206/) after the war. What he's saying is not a quote from the movie. I don't know if it's paraphrasing a specific scene; the dialog is plausible but I can't find anything like it by skimming the script.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's a reference to anything in particular, just a parody of American war movies in general.

Note that the Annotated Pratchett File [entry for Wyrd Sisters](http://www.lspace.org/books/apf/wyrd-sisters.html) doesn't have anything for this passage specifically.